# SSH tunnel throws an error: bind [ip]:801: Cannot assign requested address channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 801

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-tunnel

If I forward the port from the server to my localhost (I used my web server on apache on my other virtual machine as the server for forwarding), then everything turns out without problems.

```
ssh -L 801:192.168.0.115:80 ragzan@192.168.0.113
```

But when trying to grant access to other network members, an error occurs

```
ssh -L 192.168.0.115:801:192.168.0.115:80 ragzan@192.168.0.113

bind [192.168.0.115]:801: Cannot assign requested address 
channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 801 Could not request local forwarding.
```

And of course, when trying to access port 801, nothing worked. I tried to use different ports greater than 4000, when looking at netstat no ports are used, I killed the port but nothing happened.

When trying to use the reverse SSH tunnel, it did not give any errors, but it also failed to open localhost: 801 on the virtual machine

```
ssh -R 192.168.0.115:801:127.0.0.1:80 ragzan@192.168.0.113
```

(only on the ssh machine itself through which the tunnel was laid)

when trying to open the SSH debugger (`ssh -R 192.168.0.115:801:127.0.0.1:80 ragzan@192.168.0.113 -v`), it outputs this:

```
debug1: Remote: Forwarding listen address "192.168.0.115" overridden by server GatewayPorts 
debug1: remote forward success for: listen 192.168.0.115:801, connect 127.0.0.1:80 
debug1: Sending environment.
```

Settings: in `sshd_config` changed:

```
Gateway yes
AllowTcpForwarding yes
```

(on all computers)

When trying to connect IPv4, the result did not change (`ssh -4 -L 0.0.0.0:801:192.168.0.115:80 ragzan@192.168.0.113`)

There could have been an error in the initially incorrect setting, but when resetting all machines and installing from scratch, nothing has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For local forwarding, you need to use `-g` on the command line, or enable `GatewayPorts` to `yes` (default `no`, disabled) in `.ssh/config` or `/etc/ssh_config` to allow listening on non-localhost address:

```
ssh -g -L 192.168.0.115:801:192.168.0.115:80 ragzan@192.168.0.113
```

See [man ssh_config](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) and [man ssh](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh).

To be able to listen on non-localhost IP when doing remote forwarding, you need to enable it in the remote server's sshd_config: set `GatewayPorts` to `clientspecified` or `yes` (default `no`, disabled). See [man sshd_config](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config).

Notice, not just "Gateway" but "Gateway**Ports**". By the way, it was mentioned in the extended error message that you've got, that the reverse forwarding was overridden because of this restrictive setting. Read your error messages carefully!

Also, notice that port 801 is *privileged*. You can't listen to it as ordinary user. When doing SSH local port forwarding (`-L`) it is being bound by the client; you need to bear the `CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` capability, e.g. run ssh client as root or under [authbind](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/kinetic/en/man1/authbind.1.html) or something like this. When doing SSH remote port forwarding (`-R`), however, the port is bound by the sshd process *after* dropping privileges to the user who is authenticated, so that user needs to be root (i.e. connecting to SSH directly as root, ouch), or sshd needs to bear the same capability on the remote (that hurts again). Here's [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413807/is-there-a-way-for-non-root-processes-to-bind-to-privileged-ports-on-linux) about Linux capabilities (and there are links further).

Much easier and safer to just pick a port number above 1024.

Comment: Спасибо, решило мою проблему, только я уже писал насчёт того какие конфиги поставил и пробовал порты

Comment: Так и я о том, что вы использовали конфиги *неправильно*. Не "Gateway yes" надо было писать (как в вопросе), а "GatewayPorts yes".

Answer (score 1):

1.)

```
ssh -L 801:192.168.0.115:80 ragzan@192.168.0.113
```

It created a socket on `127.0.0.1:801` on the current machine. Everything that goes to `localhost:801` (from the local machine) will go to `.115:80` via `.113`.

This looks good.

2.)
I assume that you issued this command on the same machine as the previous one

```
ssh -L 192.168.0.115:801:192.168.0.115:80 ragzan@192.168.0.113
```

This will try to bind to `.115:801` on local machine, but this machine has no `.115` address (it seems..)

3.)

```
ssh -R 192.168.0.115:801:127.0.0.1:80 ragzan@192.168.0.113
```

This command wants to create a socket `.115:801` but remotely on the `.113` server. I assume that `.113` server has no `.115` address...

**I think you want to do the following:**

```
ssh -L your_local_ip:801:192.168.0.115:80 ragzan@192.168.0.113
```

In this case, everybody who can reach `your_local_ip:801` will be forwarded to `.115:80` via `.113`.

Comment: Yes, that's right, I sent all requests from one machine 114
I worked on three virtual machines (113,114,115) and they were in the local network, I want all users of my local network to have access to the main page of apache with the help of local port forwarding -L
 in case 3, I wonder why the debugger says that the connection was successful, but when I write localhost: 801 on machine 115 I get nothing